# Check length of a String

Tags: c++, string, string-length

I'm a beginner to C++. We are doing a project where we input firstName, lastName, and SSN for employee. Here what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Employee.h"
using namespace std;

Employee::Employee(const string &first, const string &last, const string &ssn)
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    SSN = ssn;
}

void Employee::setFirstName(const string &first)
{
    firstName = first;
}
string Employee::getFirstName() const
{
    return firstName;
}

void Employee::setLastName(const string &last)
{
    lastName = last;
}
string Employee::getLastName() const
{
    return lastName;
}

void Employee::setSSN(const string &ssn)
{
    if (ssn.length() == 9)
    {
        SSN = ssn;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Please enter SSN again: " << endl;
    }
}
string Employee::getSSN() const
{
    return SSN;
}

void Employee::print() const
{
    cout << "Employee: " << getFirstName() << ' ' << getLastName()
        << "\nSocial Security Number: " << getSSN();
}
```

My instructor wants us to check the length of the SSN (simplest way) to make sure it 9 digits, and if it's more or less, ask users to input again. I do not know how to validate the input for SSN. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Checking the length of a string and validating that string are two different questions. Care to clean up your post a bit?

Comment: @Axalo: Quit answering in comments dude

Answer (score 2):

std::string::length() is the function to be used to find length and std::string::empty() to check weather string is empty or not.

```
if(SSN.length() < 9 && !SSN.empty())
{
   //Need C++11 and above for this kind for loop
   for(auto &x: SSN)
   {
        if(std::isdigit(x))
        {
          //valid SSN
         }
   }

}
```

Comment: This won't work.  The string "HateTaxes" contains 9 characters but no digits.  It is not a valid US social security number (ssn).

Comment: Your solution won't handle the standard format of "123-45-5678", the hyphens will make the string longer.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Question was more specfic, "SSN (simplest way) to make sure it 9 digits"

Comment: How does your answer "...make sure it is 9 digits"?  I would expect use of `std::isdigit` or another method of number checking.

Comment: @ThomasMatthew Can you please tell me how could we do that then?

Comment: By the way, there is no need for the empty check.  A string that is empty has a length less than 9.

Answer (score 2):

A compact solution to this problem:

```
bool ValidSSN(const std::string& ssn) {
  if (ssn.size() != 9) return false;
  return ssn.find_first_not_of("0123456789") == ssn.npos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple and easy solution to checking the string for 9 digits.

My recommendation is a two step process:

- Verify length is 9.
- Verify string is an integral number.

*Note:  The code in the `else` clause does not work for cases such as "123Apple4".  Thanks to @Steephen for the enlightenment. Leaving the code in the answer to synchronize with comments.*

In code this would be:

```
bool is_valid = true;
if (ssn.length() != 9)
{
  is_valid = false;
}
else
{
  std::istringstream ssn_stream;
  ssn_stream.str(ssn);
  unsigned int value;
  if (!(ssn_stream >> value))
  {
    is_valid = false;
  }
}
```

Another alternative is to use a loop:

```
if (ssn.length() != 9)
{
  is_valid = false;
}
else
{
  is_valid = true;
  for (unsigned int i = 0U; i < 9; ++i)
  {
    if (!isdigit(ssn[i]))
    {
      is_valid = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:  Regular Expressions**
If your compiler supports C++ regular expression, you could come up with a regular expression to define the SSN.  You would then check if the contents of the string matched the regular expression.

Comment: Your first method is wrong. If I give input ssn_stream.str("123*"); it will consider it as a valid SSN.

Comment: @Steephen: The only way to get to the `std::istringstream` statement is for the string length to be 9.  Thus "123*" is of length 4 and sets `is_valid` to `false` and doesn't enter the second check.

Comment: what will happen if data is as follows: ssn="123******"

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a boundary case that doesn't work.  Modified answer.